# what's the proper way to sanitize data when I'm using jquery to send post data?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If the post data contains "&" character it thinks it's separating query string parameters. If it contains + it thinks it's a space. I'm sure there's some prebuilt function that takes care of these things already.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just pass your data as an object and jQuery will serialize it via [`$.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) internally, for example:

```
$.ajax({
  //options..
  data: { key: "myValue" }
});
//the same goes for shorthand methods:
$.post("url", { key: "myValue" });
```

All the magic is basic JavaScript though, [`$.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) just uses [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) underneath to do the serialization (including `&` encoding) when creating the string.

If you're sending an entire `<form>` just use [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) which serializes the entire `<form>` (all successful form elements) to the string - like a normal non-AJAX  submit would, for example:

```
$.post("url", $("form").serialize());
```

Answer (score -1):

Another option is encodeURI

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURI.asp

Comment: This is incorrect, it's `encodeURIComponent()` that should be used directly.